# paypal payment Transaction id not showing in live magento order

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.9 and when pay  payment on sandbox i got transaction id in my order listing but when pay on live server i did not get transaction id on my magento order list.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead? Also you should read [ask].

Comment: Check your IPN url either it is hitting 200 or otherwise